# A strange character

Tags: java, android

```
        String str = "ิ";
        System.out.println(str.length());
        byte[] b = str.getBytes();
        System.out.println(b[0]);
        System.out.println(b[1]);
        System.out.println(b[2]);
```

Above is my code.A speical char in `str`. It's length is one,but the `byte` is three.why? And how to make there become one? How to print this char use java code? And in my android phone this char can't delete.

Comment: could you be more elaborate?

Comment: Read up on Unicode and how to deal with it in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Its because string is "encoded" into bytes, according to documentation

Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the 
     result into a new byte array. 
The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default charset is unspecified. 
 The CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your special character is encoded using UTF-8. UTF-8 characters have different byte sizes, depending on their position in the range.

You can find the algorithm in the wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and see how the size is determined.

From the Java String `length()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()):

> The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.

Since the character is encoded using 3 bytes (whereas Unicode is one byte), you get a length of 3, rather than a length of 1 as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

- **Lenght is NOT bytes**

You have only 1 caracter, but this caracter is 3 bytes long. A String is made of several characters , but that doesnt mean that a 1 caracter string would be 1 byte.

- **About that caracter "ิ.**

Java is by default using an UNICODE (encoding. "ิ is actually 0E34, this value beeing the THAI CHARACTER SARA.)

- **About your encoding issue**

You need to change the way your application does its charset encoding and to use a utf-8 encoding instead.

Answer (score 0):

Beside all the other comments. Here a small snippet to visualize it.

```
String str = "ิ"; // \u0E34
System.out.println("character length: " + str.length());

System.out.print("bytes: ");
for (byte b : str.getBytes("UTF-8")) {
    System.out.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF).toUpperCase() + " ");
}
System.out.println("");

int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(str, 0);
System.out.println("unicode name of the codepoint: " + Character.getName(codePoint));
```

**output**

```
character length: 1
bytes: E0 B8 B4 
unicode name of the codepoint: THAI CHARACTER SARA I
```